# Tikz error for large values with \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm, 0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
%-> DEFINITIONS
\def\plthgt{50}                         % plot height
\pgfmathsetmacro\pltstp{\plthgt/4}      % plot step value

%-> DRAWING THE PLOT
\draw[thick]
    (0, 0)--
        (0, \plthgt)
    ;

\foreach \y in {0, \pltstp, ..., \plthgt}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\yvalue{4000*\y/\plthgt}
    \draw
        (0, \y)--
            (-2, \y)
            node[left]{\yvalue}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

I am trying to draw this:

[image]

I get something quite close when I do `\pgfmathsetmacro\yvalue{4*\y/\plthgt}` and `node[left]{\yvalue 00}`, with the inconvenient printing of `0.000` and the remaining values with a `.` separator.

Any solotuion for this case? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of operations. That is, compute the quotient first and then multiply:

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\yvalue{4000*(\y/\plthgt)}
```

In order to get integers, use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm, 0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
%-> DEFINITIONS
\def\plthgt{50}                         % plot height
\pgfmathsetmacro\pltstp{\plthgt/4}      % plot step value

%-> DRAWING THE PLOT
\draw[thick]
    (0, 0)--
        (0, \plthgt)
    ;

\foreach \y in {0, \pltstp, ..., \plthgt}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\yvalue{4000*(\y/\plthgt)}
    \draw
        (0, \y)--
            (-2, \y)
            node[left]{\yvalue}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to go to higher values, you need to make extra efforts such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[{x=(1mm, 0)},{y=(0,1mm)}]
%-> DEFINITIONS
\def\plthgt{50}                         % plot height
\pgfmathsetmacro\pltstp{\plthgt/4}      % plot step value

%-> DRAWING THE PLOT
\draw[thick]
    (0, 0)--
        (0, \plthgt)
    ;
\begin{scope}[/pgf/fixed point arithmetic]
\foreach \y in {0, \pltstp, ..., \plthgt}
 {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\yvalue{40000*(\y/\plthgt)}
    \draw
        (0, \y)--
            (-2, \y)
            node[left]{\yvalue}
        ;}
\end{scope}     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: I got a new problem. Why doesn't work when I try doing `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\yvalue{40000*(\y/\plthgt)}`?!

Comment: @Brasil If you want to go to even larger values, you need to load extra stuff to deal with it. Options include `\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}` (which requires the `fp` package), `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}` or some external packages like `xfp`. Which of those are you familiar/comfortable with?

Comment: I known none of them. I am still new to latex world. But I will try these you just suggest. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Just tried, but still doesn't work. :/

Comment: @Brasil I added an explicit example that works.

Comment: Great! It works! Thank you again!